# calculate 3D coordinates from UV coordinates

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I'm trying to convert the position of an object in THREE.js from a flat 2D coordinate (an annotation placed on a 2D image) to a 3D coordinate, when the image is wrapped as a texture around a 3D shape. The idea would be to place a small 3D object at equivalent 3D coordinates to represent the 2D annotation.

I can do the reverse by getting the uv.x and uv.y properties of the object that is intersected by a raycaster which is really neat.

Is the above possible in THREE? I would need to be able to account for different shape geometries.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out:

Given the UV coords of the point that you want to locate:

First you need to traverse through each triangle in the model recursively, passing in the UV coords from each, and compare against the face vertex UV array using barycentric technique to see if the point exists inside the triangle according to the UVs.

Once the correct triangle is located, you can find the related vertices for the triangle and apply the barycentric coordinates to it to get the coordinate in local space.

Then convert to world space.

Code as follows, a bit rough and ready but you get the idea:

```
// Recursively traverse through the model.
var traversePolygonsForGeometries = function (node, uvx, uvy) {
if (node.geometry) {
    // Return a list of triangles that have the point within them.
    // The returned objects will have the x,y,z barycentric coordinates of the point inside the respective triangle
    var baryData = annotationTest(uvx, uvy, node.geometry.faceVertexUvs);
    if (baryData.length) {
        for (var j = 0; j < baryData.length; j++) {
            // In my case I only want to return materials with certain names.
            if (node.geometry.faces[baryData[j][0]].daeMaterial === 
                "frontMaterial" || node.geometry.faces[baryData[j][0]].daeMaterial ===
                "print_area1_0"
                ) {
                // Find the vertices corresponding to the triangle in the model
                var vertexa = node.geometry.vertices[node.geometry.faces[baryData[j][0]].a];
                var vertexb = node.geometry.vertices[node.geometry.faces[baryData[j][0]].b];
                var vertexc = node.geometry.vertices[node.geometry.faces[baryData[j][0]].c];
                // Sum the barycentric coordinates and apply to the vertices to get the coordinate in local space
                var worldX = vertexa.x * baryData[j][1] + vertexb.x * baryData[j][2] + vertexc.x * baryData[j][3];
                var worldY = vertexa.y * baryData[j][1] + vertexb.y * baryData[j][2] + vertexc.y * baryData[j][3];
                var worldZ = vertexa.z * baryData[j][1] + vertexb.z * baryData[j][2] + vertexc.z * baryData[j][3];
                var vector = new THREE.Vector3(worldX, worldY, worldZ);
                // Translate to world space
                var worldVector = vector.applyMatrix4(node.matrixWorld);
                return worldVector;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (node.children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        var worldVectorPoint = traversePolygonsForGeometries(node.children[i], uvx, uvy);
        if (worldVectorPoint) return worldVectorPoint;
    }
}
};

// Loops through each face vertex UV item and tests if it is within the triangle.
function annotationTest(uvX, uvY, faceVertexUvArray) {
    var point = {};
    point.x = uvX;
    point.y = uvY;
    var results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < faceVertexUvArray[0].length; i++) {
        var result = ptInTriangle(point, faceVertexUvArray[0][i][0], faceVertexUvArray[0][i][1], faceVertexUvArray[0][i][2]);
        if (result.length) {
            results.push([i, result[0], result[1], result[2]]);
        }
    }
    return results;
};

// This is a standard barycentric coordinate function.
function ptInTriangle(p, p0, p1, p2) {
    var x0 = p.x;
    var y0 = p.y;
    var x1 = p0.x;
    var y1 = p0.y;
    var x2 = p1.x;
    var y2 = p1.y;
    var x3 = p2.x;
    var y3 = p2.y;

    var b0 = (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1)
    var b1 = ((x2 - x0) * (y3 - y0) - (x3 - x0) * (y2 - y0)) / b0
    var b2 = ((x3 - x0) * (y1 - y0) - (x1 - x0) * (y3 - y0)) / b0
    var b3 = ((x1 - x0) * (y2 - y0) - (x2 - x0) * (y1 - y0)) / b0

    if (b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && b3 > 0) {
        return [b1, b2, b3];
    } else {
        return [];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I didn't find much else on the topic. So I used above code to create a solution for indexed THREE.BufferGeometry in typescript.

...so to whom it may concern:

```
import {BufferGeometry, Mesh, Vector2, Vector3} from 'three';

const baryCoords = new Vector3();

const p1 = new Vector3();
const p2 = new Vector3();
const p3 = new Vector3();

const uv1 = new Vector2(0, 0);
const uv2 = new Vector2(0, 0);
const uv3 = new Vector2(0, 0);

const getVertex2d = (vertices: Float32Array, index: number, out: Vector2) => {
  out.x = vertices[index * 2] ?? 0;
  out.y = vertices[index * 2 + 1] ?? 0;
};

const getVertex = (vertices: Float32Array, index: number, out: Vector3) => {
  out.x = vertices[index * 3] ?? 0;
  out.y = vertices[index * 3 + 1] ?? 0;
  out.z = vertices[index * 3 + 2] ?? 0;
};

/**
 * Convert UV coordinates to world position
 * @param mesh mesh with indexed buffer geometry
 * @param uv
 * @param out
 * @param outNormal
 */
export const uvToWorldPosition = (
  mesh: Mesh,
  uv: Vector2,
  out: Vector3,
  outNormal?: Vector3
) => {
  const geometry = mesh?.geometry as BufferGeometry;
  const index = geometry?.getIndex()?.array! as Uint32Array;
  const vertices = geometry?.attributes.position?.array! as Float32Array
  const normals = geometry?.attributes.normal?.array! as Float32Array;

  const uvs = geometry?.attributes.uv?.array! as Float32Array;
  if (!uvs) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < index.length / 3; i++) {
    const index1 = index[i * 3]!;
    const index2 = index[i * 3 + 1]!;
    const index3 = index[i * 3 + 2]!;

    getVertex2d(uvs, index1, uv1);
    getVertex2d(uvs, index2, uv2);
    getVertex2d(uvs, index3, uv3);

    if (getBarycentricCoordinates2d(uv, uv1, uv2, uv3, baryCoords)) {
      // Find the vertices corresponding to the triangle in the model
      getVertex(vertices, index1, p1);
      getVertex(vertices, index2, p2);
      getVertex(vertices, index3, p3);

      // Sum the barycentric coordinates and apply to the vertices to get the coordinate in local space
      out.set(
        p1.x * baryCoords.x + p2.x * baryCoords.y + p3.x * baryCoords.z,
        p1.y * baryCoords.x + p2.y * baryCoords.y + p3.y * baryCoords.z,
        p1.z * baryCoords.x + p2.z * baryCoords.y + p3.z * baryCoords.z
      );

      // Translate to world space
      out.applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);

      if (outNormal) {
        // Find the normals corresponding to the triangle in the model
        getVertex(normals, index1, p1);
        getVertex(normals, index2, p2);
        getVertex(normals, index3, p3);

        outNormal.set(
          p1.x * baryCoords.x + p2.x * baryCoords.y + p3.x * baryCoords.z,
          p1.y * baryCoords.x + p2.y * baryCoords.y + p3.y * baryCoords.z,
          p1.z * baryCoords.x + p2.z * baryCoords.y + p3.z * baryCoords.z
        );
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

const signedArea = (v1: Vector2, v2: Vector2, v3: Vector2) => {
  return (v1.x - v3.x) * (v2.y - v3.y) - (v1.y - v3.y) * (v2.x - v3.x);
}

/**
 * Check if a point is inside a triangle and return barycentric coordinates
 * @param p
 * @param v1
 * @param v2
 * @param v3
 * @param out
 * @return true if the point is inside the triangle
 */
function getBarycentricCoordinates2d(p: Vector2, v1: Vector2, v2: Vector2, v3: Vector2, out: Vector3) {
  const b0 = signedArea(v1, v2, v3);
  if (b0 == 0) return false;

  const b1 = signedArea(v2, v3, p) / b0;
  if (b1 <= 0) return false;

  const b2 = signedArea(v3, v1, p) / b0;
  if (b2 <= 0) return false;

  const b3 = signedArea(v1, v2, p) / b0;
  if (b3 <= 0) return false;

  out.set(b1, b2, b3);
  return true;
}
```